# Using javascript function and variables in combination with PHP and MYSQL

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

On my page I have a search result that contains a list with users where each is followed by an "**addfriend**" button. Each row contains a **username** and **userID**. Meanwhile the ID of the user that requested the searchresult is stored in a Session variable.

When the addfriend-botton is clicked the following 2 things should happen:

1. Store the **userID** and **$_SESSION['userID']** is a MySQL table which describes the relationship.
2. Do **NOT refresh** the page (this the core of my problem) but stay focussed and change the state of the button to e.g. "friend request send". I'm thinking of GetElementByID().style method.

I was thinking of this:

```
<a href="#" onClick="addFriend('<? echo $_SESSION['userID'];?>','<? echo $rij['userID']; ?>')">
```

which calls the **javascript function addfriend**

I was hoping to catch the two ID's like this:

```
<script>
function addfriend(id1, id2)
{
    //server side php code where I use value of 
    //the client-side javascript variables: +id1+ and +id2+ .
}
</script>
```

Is this at all possible or I'm I thinking the wrong way? Any suggetions on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

You are in the right way, inside your addFriend() function, you can call one php file (via AJAX) and send the IDS without refresh the page. I think better you work with Jquery in this case, something like this:

```
<script>
function addfriend(id1, id2)
{
   $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'yourPHPfile.php',
        data: { your_id_1:id1, your_id_2:id2 },
        success: function(data){
                    if(data){
                       alert('Done!');
                    }
        },
        dataType: 'text'
    });
}
</script>
```

And in your PHP File you can do this:

```
<?php
    //receive Ids
    $id1 = $_POST['your_id_1'];
    $id2 = $_POST['your_id_2'];

    //do something here

    echo "OK!";
<?
```

to do this work you need download and add the jQuery plugin in your page, rather into head tag

```
<head>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>          
</head>
```

Good work and don't give up! (:

Comment: The script works, but still the boolean data gives FALSE. Is there a way to view the error by error handling?

Comment: run the script with Firebug for Firefox... you can view the response of ajax

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using AJAX (asynchronous JavaScript and XML), which is really just a fancy term for "sending stuff to a server with JavaScript and getting a response back, without reloading the page". There's nothing special about AJAX; it just involves using plain old JavaScript to send an HTTP request.

Check out [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com), a JavaScript library that handles most of the technical stuff for you. Specifically, look at its [post()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) function, which allows you to send data to a PHP script using the $_POST system variable. There are lots of clear examples on that page.

Note that you don't *need* jQuery to use AJAX; jQuery is just a library that makes things easier. If you really want to learn how the JavaScript side of AJAX works, try following one of the many tutorials out there, such as [Mozilla's](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started) or [this one](http://www.h3xed.com/programming/beginner-ajax-guide-get-and-post-examples).

Comment: Allthough not a direct answer, it very usefull for me, Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

[AJAX](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp) is the answer you're looking for.

It sounds like you already have a basic understanding of this, but to clarify, Javascript executes on the client side, and PHP executes on the server side. So you would have to make a call back to your server in order to interact with PHP/MySQL.

The purpose of AJAX is to do this without requiring a page refresh.

Comment: Try to find a better article than w3fools :)

Comment: @Jack: Disagree. Sure w3schools could use improvement by doing something like wiki-fying their site, but IMO it is a great resource for a beginner to learn a new concept. The vast majority of the complaints on [w3fools](http://w3fools.com/) are rather nit-picky, and don't really make much difference to a beginning user. Show me a better tutorial for a beginner.

Comment: [When should I vote down?](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-down) Does my answer match the criteria of "egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended," or "clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect?"

Comment: You can disagree with me all you want, I'm not the one who down voted :)

Comment: @Jack: Sorry, I wasn't trying to accuse you of being the person who downvoted (I figured it wasn't you), and I do appreciate you offering some kind of explanation as to why someone might have. But it does irk me a bit when people downvote with no explanation, especially when it's clearly exactly what the OP is looking for. And my question still stands, do you know of a better resource for a beginner's tutorial? When I started out, I learned a LOT from w3schools, and everyone I've ever seen that says "w3fools" has yet to offer a better alternative.

Comment: Sure, you can cite [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started) or something, but usually, the documentation for these kinds of things don't really work as a great tutorial for those that don't know anything about what they're trying to learn. Sure, they have a "how to," but one thing I found to be invaluable when I was learning was the Try-It-Yourself editor on w3schools. Sorry to be long-winded about this topic, guess I just don't like seeing a tool that I found so useful getting thrown under the bus because someone thought of a clever name to criticize it.